# Upgrading to aem62 issue

Tags: aem

Attempting to migrate from `aem6.0SP3` to `6.2` throws an error while compiling our project:

```
missing requirement [ewcs.my-bundle [474](R 474.3)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.day.cq.commons)(version>=5.7.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))
Unresolved requirements: [[ewcs.my-bundle [474](R 474.3)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.day.cq.commons)(version>=5.7.0)(!(version>=6.0.0)))]
```

We do not see the library referenced in our `pom.xml` even when we do dependency:tree, any suggestion?

Update: missing `twitter4j v.3.0.5` but mvn repo does not have it

[image]

Comment: Make use of the UberJar should help with these sorts of issues. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html

Comment: @mickleroy thank you, Uber and cq-social-blog allows my files compiled but page not loading, I saw missing twitter4j v3.0.5 but maven does not have the file. Not sure if I am moving to right direction.

Comment: So your project is compiling successfully but you're seeing misisng dependencies for your bundle? Could you post a screenshot of the bundle definition from the system console?

Comment: @mickleroy screenshot attached. It may/may not be related to the blank page I get but this is the only error in system console for error "The absolute uri: http://www.my.com/ew/my/taglib/1.0 cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
"

Comment: unless your application makes use of the "ACS Commons Twitter Support" bundle, I wouldn't worry about that. Are there any dependencies highlighted in red in your own bundle?

Comment: @mickleroy nope, this is the only red

Comment: @user5733033 Have you got any solution for this? I am running into the same error. I have upgraded from6.1 to 6.3 and my pages are also blank.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest ACE Commons package for 6.2. You can download the relevant version from:

https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/adobe/aem/uber-jar/

Note that there is a new version of Uber-Jar for 6.2 SP1 so make sure you are using the correct version.

Twitterfj is not a part of Adobe public repo but if you really want it, you can download it from here:

https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/com.adobe.acs.bundles.twitter4j/releases/tag/com.adobe.acs.bundles.twitter4j-1.0.0

More information is available at:

http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/twitter.html